# Sort Tool with Custom Objects by date

Tags: sorting, object, arraylist, velocity, selection-sort

I have a list of TestRecord objects in velocity which have a method getDateExecuted which returns a java.util.date object. I would like to sort the Records by date using the sort tool.(or appropriate sorting algorithm) However I have not seen any implementations of the sort tool that aren't using an xPath node as the list argument. If the sort tool can not  be used any information on creating a bubble/selection sort using only foreach loops would be helpful.

sort tool documentation: 
http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html

http://www.hannonhill.com/kb/Script-Formats/#sort-tool

Answer (score 1):

Add the SortTool object to the context:

```
context.put("sortTool", new SortTool());
```

In the template, you can get the sorted list (sorted by dateExecuted) as :

```
#foreach($testRecord in $sortTool.sort($testRecordList, "dateExecuted:asc"))
    $testRecord.dateExecuted
#end
```

It is clearly specified in the SortTool documentation
http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html

> Let me know for any issue